# Reporting tools for auditd

Tags: linux, puppet, audit, reporting, alerts

I need to set up auditing in my environment, specifically file integrity monitoring.  I've tried [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net/), but found it cumbersome.  I've since discovered `auditd` (already installed on my CentOS 6 system) and found it to be a simple but powerful auditing solution.

I'm aware of the command line tool `aureport` for generating stats or lists of file changes recorded by `auditd`, and it works nicely.  However, I've got about 100 Linux hosts currently, and need to find a smoother way to be alerted to changes to critical files.  Are there any open source reporting tools or dashboards out there that sit on top of `auditd` for aggregating multiple hosts on a network?  I haven't seen anything when searching the net and [github](http://github.com).

As a bonus, it would be convenient to have the file changes reported by auditd to be combined with file change reports from puppet reports from the puppetmaster/puppetDB host to show that a change was expected and to not fire an alert or be shown in the report.

Any recommendations on existing solutions or tips on this file integrity monitoring topic?

Answer (score 4):

Recent versions of auditd have a dispatcher that supports sending events to syslog so you can perform the processing through your centralized logging system (assuming you have one).

Edit: puppet supports syslog as a log dest so you could do correlation there as well.